# Regex to split on last dot if there is 1 after dot

Tags: regex

I would like to split this kind of strings into two groups:

```
    aaa.aa.aa.1
    aaa.aa.aa
    bbbbb.1
    bbbbb
```

to have in first group chars before .1 and in the other group 1 or empty if there is not 1 at the end:

```
   aaa.aa.aa     1
   aaa.aa.aa     
   bbbbb         1
   bbbbb
```

I would like to achieve this one with one regex. I came up with `(\S*).(1)`, but it does not split, if there is not 1 at the end.

Comment: The `1` is not optional in your regular expression. What do you expect if the input is `aaa.aa.aa.`? Looks like it would match `aaa.aa.aa` and drop the last dot. Is that correct?

Comment: I do not expect `aaa.aa.aa.`, but match `aaa.aa.aa` and drop the last dot is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `(\S*?)(?:\.(1)$|$)`

**Explanation**

`(\S*?)` - the `\S*` from your pattern with an added lazy quantifier (`?`). This will match as few characters as possible

`(?: ... )` - Non-capturing group to maintain your desired capture group numbers

`\.(1)$|$` - (1) literal dot `\.` followed by a litteral `1` (stored in capture group) followed by the end of string `$` OR (2) end of string (in case `.1` is not present)

**Sample Test**

INPUT:

```
aaa.aa.aa.1
aaa.aa.aa
bbbbb.1
bbbbb
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] aaa.aa.aa    [2] 1
[1] aaa.aa.aa    [2] (empty)
[1] bbbbb        [2] 1
[1] bbbbb        [2] (empty)
```

**NOTE**: Asked in comments about situation `aaa.aa.aa.` and it was established this is not expected input. This pattern will *not* drop the last dot since there is no `1`

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks!